# Adding a view with 100% height in Titanium does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm having a display problem when I try to add a View with 100% height in Titanium - it appears correctly on Android but not on iOS. Here's a simplified code:

```
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'win',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var s = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    backgroundColor:'red',
    layout: 'horizontal'
});

var r = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    width:300,
    height:'100%' // problem
})

s.add(r);

win.add(s);
win.open();
```

Result on Android (correct):
[image: Android]

Result on iPad:
[image: iPad]

It does work if I set the height to a finite number, but I want the view to cover the entire height. How can I accomplish this, and why doesn't 100% height work on iOS?

Comment: please note, the titanium platform is not meant for building the app just once. The best way to build apps is build 1 backend, and for both platforms create a different UI so it fits the purpose of the OS better. For doing this on an iPad, you could also use splitwindow: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPad.SplitWindow-object.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with adding a `view` to a `view`. If you add the `yellow view` to the `window`, and give `zIndex` to the both views, it works correctly.

For aligning it left, you should use `left: 0;`, not `layout: 'horizontal'` as according to the documentation the layout property does not exists: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Window-object

```
var s = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    backgroundColor:'red',
    zIndex: 1
});

var r = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    width:300,
    height:'100%', // no problem
    zIndex: 2,
    left: 0
});

win.add(r);
```

Comment: The yellow view appears in the center with your suggestion. If I add a `layout:'horizontal'` to the window nothing shows up.

Comment: add: `left: 0`, or right of you will. On default, it centers the view or whatever you add. With css style top/bottom/left/right you can position it correctly. This is both with height and width the case

Comment: Also, the layout property does not show up on the documentation: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Window-object. I updated my post to suit this question too